# Assigning multiple associative to one

Tags: php, associative-array

I am trying to add a question and I have 4 options for that question. Among those options, only one will be the correct of course. But, after submitting the form, I am receiving the data like the following:

```
Array
(
    [option_A] => answera
    [option_B] => answerb
    [option_C] => answersc
    [option_D] => answerd
)
```

I want to reassign those array with a single key like the following:

```
Array
(
    [answers] => Array
        (
            [0] => answerd
            [1] => answerb
            [2] => answerc
            [3] => answerd
        )

)
```

Is it possible to get the result I am expecting? Can this be acheive with the function `array_walk()`?

Comment: Is it Mandate that you should be using array_walk, It can be done without that also. I can help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as below. By Creating new array.

```
<?php

$Output = array();

$input = array("option_A" => "answera", "option_B" => "answerb", "option_C" => "answersc"
    , "option_D" => "answerd");

foreach ($input as $key => $value) 
{   $PArray[] = $value; }

$Output["answers"] = $PArray; 

echo "<pre>";print_r($Output);exit();

?>
```

Comment: I have edited my question can you please have a look?

Comment: I have Updated my answer accordingly please check now.